# Difficulty aligning h1 and h2 with CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm having difficulty vertically aligning the 'h1' red notification bubble with the 'h2' tag next to it.
Was I on the right track trying to use `display: inline-block;` or completely off.
I also tried using `vertical-align:middle`but that didn't seem to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.steps h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.steps {
  width: 100%;
  height: 405px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9%;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
label {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2C3E50;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
label h2 span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.new {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FF4447;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <h2>Your Matches</h2>
  <ul id="matches">
    <li>
      <h1 class="new">1!</h1>
      <label for="label-1">

        <h2>Steve, 28 <span>Matched 2 days ago</span></h2>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="label-2">
        <h2>Tony, 30 <span>Matched 1 hour ago</span></h2> 
      </label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label for="label-3">
        <h2>Bruce<span>Matched 4 days ago</span></h2> 
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?
[image: Is this what you mean?]

If so, you're thinking along the right lines. Another alternative to previously mentioned solutions is to just move the `h1` inside the `label` where the `h1` (basically the contents of the label) you want it next to is, inside the actual `label` element, as a child. You also need to change your `label h2 span` to `display: inline;`.

(HTML)

```
<li>
  <label for="label-1">
    <h1 class="new">1!</h1>
    <h2>Steve, 28 <span>Matched 2 days ago</span></h2>
  </label>
</li>
```

(CSS)

```
label h2 span {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.new {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FF4447;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks!

Comment: No problem at all! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand what you are trying to do but here is my quick solution:

You can set the element position by adding this to your CSS:

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 10rem;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/teroqavejo/edit?html,css,output)